# How do you use nAnt to copy files to a non-domain machine

Tags: nant

I have a nAnt script that works perfectly to build and copy a website to another domain machine. However, when I try to copy the website to a machine not on the domain I get security errors.

I know it's because the user that I have set to run nAnt doesn't have permissions on the remote computer.

Is it possible to specify a remote user to authenticate against when trying to copy files to a non-domain computer? There doesn't seem to be any options for this in the official nAnt documentation.

What other options are available?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We've got round this by having a account with the same username and password on all servers that are involved in the copy. However, we do it the other way round. We copy from a machine in a workgroup to a maching in a domain and it works fine.

e.g. useraccount on workgroup computer:
.\CruiseControl password1

useraccount on domain:
domain\CruiseControl password1

Comment: That's not a bad idea. I'll give it a shot.

Comment: This method worked perfectly.
I'm running the nAnt process with a domain account (via Cruise Control), and created a local verion of that domain account on the DMZ server.
Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 1):

I've stumbled upon the same problem. Ended up using [PsExec](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb897553) to call XCOPY. Works fine.

Answer (score 0):

I answered [a question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/344591/how-to-use-nant-teamcity-to-deploy-across-dmz#347775) that was similar to this.

One might be able to use the exec task to launch the [runas](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb490994.aspx) command to copy (or xcopy) the files over to a computer with a different username/password. If this is a non-domain account, you might have to use the local administrator account to authenticate. I'm not 100% on that one.

This should allow you to stay within NAnt. Let me know if this is not sufficient and we can try and figure something else out.

Comment: That does give some ideas, but none that would work easily.

I'm not using Team City.


SCP uses the username environment variable, but doesn't specify a password.

If necessary, I could just use exec to use ftp to deploy everything, but I would rather stick to using nAnt to handle it if I possible.

Comment: Updated the answer as some of this still might apply to you.

Comment: I think trying to run a local nant as a remote admin and then using xcopy is getting into the same boat as using ftp, just using a different external program. It looks like I may have to go the FTP route.